# Is it possible to get the character after "Shift" has been pressed, without pressing shift?

Tags: .net, silverlight, encoding, character, culture

Is it possible to get the character if "Shift" was Pressed, that is, if I press "1" I get the "1" character, but if I hold down "Shift" it becomes "!" - all without the quotes of course. How do I do something like this programatically?

There was a method where you could just add to the ASCII code. However, this option is not suitable as it won't work in every locale.

Is there an option which will work in .NET, and possibly in Silverlight, where I can pass in a character like "9" and get the result "("?

Programmatically pressing "Shift" will not work in this case nor will any SendKeys based solution due to platform limitations.

This would be for a virtual keyboard, like the on-screen keyboard in Silverlight.

Comment: there must be some way to interrogate the keyboard mapping for this information, but since I don't know what it is I'm going to comment instead of answer.

Comment: and what about touch screen keyboard layouts? or handy/smart/mobile etc? They're often significantly different.

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid: many open questions here, if you've got the time can you answer them so we know what direction you'd like to take?

Comment: Outputting non-visible keyboard characters to get their behaviour is something I guess is not that common, and I realise now it is locale/culture dependant, if there was a .NET library with keyboard layout data in it I could use this with a lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just spend a few minutes making a mapping table of your own?

```
1->!
2->@
3->#
etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: Don't forget that there are different keyboard layouts (with possibly even different codes on different platforms such as Mac vs. Windows). E.g. on a German keyboard you would get double quotes on Shift+2.

Comment: What about us with non-us keyboards? (This is my equivalent of what you started typing: §!"#¤%&/()=?`)

Comment: Depends on the site needs. If he knows it'll be limited to one region, not a problem.

Comment: Keyboard layout is irrespective (though related) to the region. I'm in a "Dutch region" and (unfortunately) deal with three types of keyboard layouts daily: US International on one, Dutch on another and German on the laptop.

Comment: This was something I thought about after asking this question - this may be acceptable, as the layout will be fixed (En-GB).
I thought about this before a while ago however I'm converting an old solution to Silverlight and thought I'd ask if this was possible any other way.

Comment: +1. Its simple, it will work for a known keyboard layout and doesn't need access to APIs that are unlikely to be available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to return the question: how do you know what keyboard layout is used? I.e., on one of my systems, the number 2 has the @-sign. On another, it has the "-sign (double quote). You say the 9 has the (-sign, but mine has the (-sign on top of the 0 and the )-sign on top of the minus-sign.

Windows comes by default with hundreds of [keyboard mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) (i.e., Uzbek Cyrillic, US International, US Default, Dutch, German and German IBM etc). [AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) vs [QWERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) and so on.

The real question could be: how to read a keyboard mapping in windows programmatically. I don't know. While it will be possible if you find out how you can interface with the driver files, you'll probably be quicker off using a mapping based on, for instance, the layouts in my [first link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) above. When you read the keyboard type from the registry, it'll cover the majority of cases.

Alternatively, you can consider programmatically setting the [sticky keys](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/stickykeys.aspx) for Shift (set sticky keys, send Shift key message and you're done).

(note that ASCII has nothing to do with keyboard scan codes. While it might've worked for some systems, it'd never have worked reliably for all.)

EDIT: consider trying the [keyboard layout creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) from Microsoft. Following it's creation process and a bit of reverse engineering, it can't be hard to find out how keyboard layouts are written. Yet, if all you need is support for one keyboard layout, take that one in the editor, reverse the Shift-action and simply programmatically set your newly created keyboard layout (and change it back) before and after someone starts typing.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you'll have to do quite a bit of API groveling.

You can start here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920537.aspx

More good reading:
http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/handson/dev/unicode-kbdsonwindows.pdf

Comment: Seems he is on Silverlight, so there won't be any Windows API :-(

Comment: I've done this before in VB6 it worked fine - but as mentioned this API is not available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

For exactly that purpose, WPF and SilverLight offer the [**`TextInput`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput%28VS.96%29.aspx) event. The character entered will be contained in the [`TextCompositionEventArgs.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.text%28VS.96%29.aspx) property. The event already considers user locale and keyboard layout:

```
private void Window_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Text contains the character that corresponds to the
    // key combination that was pressed
    Trace.WriteLine("TEXT: " + e.Text);
}
```

This actually might not solve your problem, since you specifically asked about a conversion function. I'm not aware of such a function in WPF/Silverlight (There is the `KeyConverter` class, but its purpose is a different one; you can use it to map both number keys and number keys on the numpad to the same key). However, you must be getting the key codes from somewhere, and if that's the keyboard this event should perfectly do.

In Windows Forms applications (which seems not relevant here though) the corresponding event to get the actual character would be `Control.KeyPress`.

Comment: It is possible to read the Shift and Key values when together, but not to write them as output e.g. Shift+2 gets " instead of 2

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. What are you actually trying to achieve? If you need both, i.e. the keys pressed + corresponding character, you will have to listen to both (Preview)KeyDown and (Preview)TextInput events.

Comment: I was not sure how to phrase my original question, so sorry if it was ambigious however I want to output to screen what the result of Shift + Character would be, and wondered if this was possible, as it may be of use to others. Getting the Shift Key+Character is possible using the KeyPress/KeyDown events even in Silverlight.

Comment: Where do you find the TextInput event in Silverlight??

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: It is new in Silverlight 4.0. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput%28VS.96%29.aspx.

Comment: I did not realise this was new to Silverlight 4.0 as I had not looked at them until this was mentioned. Guess I would have been stuck if I wanted to get the character and shift key combination pressed!

Answer (score -1):

find the math in behind the numbers of each character and work with it...